# Reverse a Linked List in groups of given size

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

Given a linked list, reverse the nodes of a linked list k at a time and return its modified list.

k is a positive integer and is less than or equal to the length of the linked list. If the number of nodes is not a multiple of k then left-out nodes, in the end, should remain as it is.

You may not alter the values in the list's nodes, only nodes themselves may be changed.

[image]
[image]

but when I am using the code below, My Output: [3,2,1,5,4]

How to do this in correct way?

```
class Solution
{
    public static Node reverse(Node head, int k)
    {
        Node prev = null;
        Node dummy = head;
        int c = 0;

        while(dummy != null && c < k ) {
            Node next = dummy.next;
            dummy.next = prev;
            prev = dummy;
            dummy = next;
            c++;
        }
        if(dummy != null) {
            head.next = reverse(dummy,k);
        }
        return prev;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d write an auxiliary method

```
private boolean areAtLeastNNodes(int n, Node head)
```

So before trying to reverse anything I’d call this method. If it returns false, I will abstain from reversing.

My own version of `areAtLeastNNodes()` would be recursive because I would find it simpler. It could also be iterative.

My suggestion means passing twice over each sublist, once for counting and once for reversing. This feels like a waste. Surely this could be avoided, but it would be complicated, I would not want to bother.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, write a method that calculates the list's length. Later, keep track on index of item you are currently reversing, by incrementing some counter every time you increment `c`.

Later, instead of checking if (`dummy != null`) before recurently calling the `reverse` method, you should rather check if there is enough elements left in your list - by comparing the list's length calculated at the beginning with the counter.

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion there's no need to count the length of the list. However, the pointer manipulation is a little tricky.

```
public static Node reverseK(Node head, int k)
{
    return reverseK(head, head, k, k);
}

private static Node reverseK(Node head, Node node, int i, int k)
{
    // we reached a final sequence of length < k, return the current head
    if(node == null) 
        return head;
    
    if(i == 1)
    {           
        // we reached the end of a sequence of length k. 
        // Reverse the next sequence, return the new head.
        head.next = reverseK(node.next, node.next, k, k);
        return node;
    }
    
    // Store current next as it will be modified by the recursive call.
    Node next = node.next;
    
    Node newHead = reverseK(head, node.next, i-1, k);

    // If the current sequence was of length k, reverse pointers.
    if(newHead != head)
    {
        next.next = node;
    }
    
    return newHead;
}
```

Test:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Node head = build(a);

print(head);

head = reverseK(head, 3);

print(head);
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
3 2 1 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think about a method using the modulus, k. At each step of the iteration, the current node can get the value for its "next" field either from the function caller or from the result of the recursive call.

Python code:

```py
def print_list(node, k):
  i = 0
  s = ""
  while node:
    s += node['val']
    node = get_next(node)
    if i == k - 1:
      s += " "
    i = (i + 1) % k
  print(s)

def get_next(node):
  return node['next']

def set_next(node, new_next):
  node['next'] = new_next


# Returns (this_block_head, next_block_head)
def reverse(node, k, new_next=None, m=0):
  if k == 1:
    return (node, None)

  # We use 'this_block_head' as a signal
  # that when returns this current node,
  # it means the block's length is less than
  # k, and therefore will not be reversed.

  if not node:
    return (None, None) if m == 0 else (new_next, None)

  # The first node in
  # a block doesn't get
  # a next parameter and
  # must get it from the
  # recursive call.

  next_param = None if m == k - 1 else node

  (this_block_head, next_block_head) = reverse(get_next(node), k, next_param, (m + 1) % k)

  if this_block_head == node:
    # When 'new_next' is null,
    # this is a beginning of a block
    # so the caller needs the node
    # as its 'this_block_head'.
    return (new_next if new_next else node, None)

  # The last in the block,
  # which will become first,
  # here 'this_block_head' is
  # actually 'next_block_head'
  if m == k - 1:
    set_next(node, new_next)
    return (node, this_block_head)

  set_next(node, next_block_head if m == 0 else new_next)
  return (this_block_head, next_block_head)
```

Output:

```py
def reset_list():
  global a, b, c, d, e, f
  f = {'val': 'f', 'next': None}
  e = {'val': 'e', 'next': f}
  d = {'val': 'd', 'next': e}
  c = {'val': 'c', 'next': d}
  b = {'val': 'b', 'next': c}
  a = {'val': 'a', 'next': b}

reset_list()
print_list(a, 6)  # abcdef
reverse(a, 2)
print_list(b, 2)  # ba dc fe

print("")

reset_list()
print_list(a, 6)  # abcdef
reverse(a, 3)
print_list(c, 3)  # cba fed

print("")

reset_list()
print_list(a, 6)  # abcdef
reverse(a, 4)
print_list(d, 4)  # dcba ef
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do something like this,

For below example you will receive this response

```
4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 5 -> 6
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node n1 = new Node(1);
        Node n2 = new Node(2);
        Node n3 = new Node(3);
        Node n4 = new Node(4);
        Node n5 = new Node(5);
        Node n6 = new Node(6);
        n1.next = n2;
        n2.next = n3;
        n3.next = n4;
        n4.next = n5;
        n5.next = n6;

        System.out.println(reverse(n1, n1, n1.next, 4));
    }

    public static Node reverse(Node fst, Node lst, Node nxt, int k) {
        if (k == 1) {
            return fst;
        } else {
            Node m1 = fst;
            Node m2 = nxt.next;

            fst = nxt;
            fst.next = m1;
            lst.next = m2;

            return reverse(fst, lst, lst.next, --k);
        }
    }
}

class Node {
    public int val;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (next == null) {
            return "" + val;
        } return val + " -> " + next.toString();
    }
}
```